# Windows 2012 R2 RDP - How to force a default desktop background for AD users on remote sessions only?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I want to setup either through a GPO or through some other method a default desktop background for my users when they sign in to our RDP environment. I do not want to force the background on them on their local machines. The reason I want to do this is to clue them in that the desktop they're looking at is the remote desktop on the server and not their local machine. Can anyone help me out with how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

What you want is loopback policy. Normally, users policies are applied to user containers, and computer policies are applied to computer containers. Loopback policies are user policies that are applied to computer containers, and they affect users that log in to computers in that container.

The loopback option is an option that is turned on in the policy in question.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2013/02/08/circle-back-to-loopback/

Answer (score 1):

Desktop Backgrounds do not work for a terminal session. It says so at the bottom of the policy when you configure it